# Javascript Regular Expression Matching Simpler Method

Tags: javascript

I have following code to match a string with format **1ab11ab111**

where **1**= Any Number **0 to 9**

and **a** or **b** = Any character **a to z or A to Z**

```
var str = "1ab11ab111";
var patt1 = /[0-9]+[a-z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[a-z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]/i;
```

So is there any simpler method/ code for the same string match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression you provided would match any string containing lower case letters and numbers.

I think you actually want:

```
/^\d[a-z]{2}\d{2}[a-z]{2}\d{3}$/i
```

Here's how I tested:

```
/^\d[a-z]{2}\d{2}[a-z]{2}\d{3}$/i.test('1ab11ab111'); // true
/^\d[a-z]{2}\d{2}[a-z]{2}\d{3}$/i.test('1ab11Ab111'); // true
/^\d[a-z]{2}\d{2}[a-z]{2}\d{3}$/i.test('1ab11ab11'); // false
```

Comment: But **a** or **b** can be either lower or uppercase characters. And your code is checking only for lowercase

Comment: I just updated it. You should also make that clear in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Well `[0-9]` can be simplified to `\d`. If each one of those character classes is meant to match exactly one character (rather than one or more as it does now), you can similar character classes together with a single `{…}` quantifier, like this:

```
var patt1 = /\d[a-z]{2}\d{2}[a-z]{2}\d{3}/;
```

This will match and string consisting of a single digit, followed by two lower case Latin letters, followed by two digits, followed by two lower case Latin letters, followed by three digits.

But it can be simplified even more by grouping certain elements together, like this:

```
var patt1 = /(\d[a-z]\d){2}\d{2}/;
```

This will match all of a single digit, followed by two lower case Latin letters, followed by  a single digit, captured into group 1, which must appear twice, followed by two digits.

Also note, both these will match any sequence of characters which matches this pattern anywhere in the string—e.g. `'foo1ab11ab111bar'` would be a valid match. If this is a problem, use a start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchor to prevent any characters appearing before or after the matched substring, like this:

```
var patt1 = /^(\d[a-z]\d){2}\d{2}$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/[0-9][a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z]+[0-9]+/
```

Should be enough

For the exact match you should do this where a and b can be a uppercase letter as you requested:

```
/[0-9][a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}/
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/vX0hJ7)

Comment: But When I am giving **1ab111ab111** instead of **1ab11ab111** its showing me string match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use    `/[0-9][a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-z]{2}[0-9]{3}/i`

You can use `\d` in place of `[0-9]`. Thus the pattern will be using `\d`

```
/\d[a-z]{2}\d{2}[a-z]{2}\d{3}/i
```

You test this at http://regex101.com/r/fS9cB6

Comment: This would match `99999929329012321AAABABSABAbas1ab11ab111fdisjaoifjio33` which I'm pretty sure you don't want. You need to add the `^` and `$`.

Comment: @BillCriswell Its not matching your string with above code .
http://jsfiddle.net/y6g5e/1/

Comment: @hsaka I mean, comparing the result of `match` with a string is expected to fail...

Comment: @hsaka The way your testing the string for a match in that fiddle is wrong. See [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/y6g5e/2/)

Comment: You're welcome... Next time please check before posting : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match.